# Auto margin not working on i tag using font awesome

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using  font awesome http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ to create my icons. For this I have added an icon inside an anchor tag. In this anchor tag I am not able to center the icon which is nothing but text with respect to HTML

http://jsfiddle.net/sK2V5/7/

```
 <a class="ico" href="#"><i class="icon-help"></i></a>

i:before
{
  content:"\260E";
}

.ico {
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
   width:36px;
  }

.ico i {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: inline-block; 
}

 .ico i:before {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the  to be centered inside .ico you should be able to set the parent (.ico) to text-align:center;

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto;` only works if the:

a) Element is `display: block;`

b) Has fixed width.

c) Isn't floating.

Try this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7g2bu/)

```
.ico i {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try text-align: center to .ico class

```
.ico {
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
   width:36px;
   text-align: center;
  }
```